the type parameter `C` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
I have struct.
struct Create<F> {
    f: F,
}

and a trait
trait Observable {
    fn subscribe(&self);
}

Now I want to implement the trait to the struct.
This code is working. Which means rust compiler can know the C from F: Fn() -> C.
impl<C, F> Observable for Create<F>
where
    C: Clone,
    F: Fn() -> C,
{
    fn subscribe(&self) {}
}

But this code has compile error: the type parameter C is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
Which means rust compiler can't know the C from F: Fn(C).
impl<C, F> Observable for Create<F>
where
    C: Clone,
    F: Fn(C),
{
    fn subscribe(&self) {}
}

Rust compiler can infer the C from F: Fn() -> C, but not from F: Fn(C).
Why is it? What's the deeper reason for it?
full code
struct Create<F> {
    f: F,
}

trait Observable {
    fn subscribe(&self);
}

// This code is working
// impl<C, F> Observable for Create<F>
// where
//     C: Clone,
//     F: Fn() -> C,
// {
//     fn subscribe(&self) {}
// }

// This code has compile error: the type parameter `C` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
impl<C, F> Observable for Create<F>
where
    C: Clone,
    F: Fn(C),
{
    fn subscribe(&self) {}
}


Is Create.f always impl Fn(_)->_? If so, try define pub struct Create<F: Fn(I) -> O, I, O> { f: F, _io: std::marker::PhantomData<(I,O)>, }
